# Add/Edit/Delete rows with select option - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am using JavaScript to add/delete/edit rows. The row includes 4 textbox and one selection box. When I click on edit I am able to change the value of textbox but for selection box as the option dont appear  I am not able to do it and also even on clicking Save the value of checkbox is not stored correctly(it stores the value not the description). Can you please help me finding the error in script ?

```js
function edit_row(no) {
  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "block";

  var ffcode = document.getElementById("ffcode_row" + no);
  var ffname = document.getElementById("ffname_row" + no);
  var fftype = document.getElementById("fftype_row" + no);
  var ffdate = document.getElementById("ffdate_row" + no);

  var ffcode_data = ffcode.innerHTML;
  var ffname_data = ffname.innerHTML;
  var fftype_data = fftype.innerHTML;
  var ffdate_data = ffdate.innerHTML;

  ffcode.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='ffcode_text" + no + "' value='" + ffcode_data + "'>";
  ffname.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='ffname_text" + no + "' value='" + ffname_data + "'>";
  fftype.innerHTML = "<input type='select' id='fftype_text" + no + "' value='" + fftype_data + "'>";
  ffdate.innerHTML = "<input type='date' id='ffdate_text" + no + "' value='" + ffdate_data + "'>";
}

function save_row(no) {
  var ffcode_val = document.getElementById("ffcode_text" + no).value;
  var ffname_val = document.getElementById("ffname_text" + no).value;
  var fftype_val = document.getElementById("fftype_text" + no).value;
  var ffdate_val = document.getElementById("ffdate_text" + no).value;

  document.getElementById("ffcode_row" + no).innerHTML = ffcode_val;
  document.getElementById("ffname_row" + no).innerHTML = ffname_val;
  document.getElementById("fftype_row" + no).innerHTML = fftype_val;
  document.getElementById("ffdate_row" + no).innerHTML = ffdate_val;

  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "none";
}

function delete_row(no) {
  document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
}

function add_row() {
  var new_ffcode = document.getElementById("new_ffcode").value;
  var new_ffname = document.getElementById("new_ffname").value;
  var new_fftype = document.getElementById("new_fftype").value;
  var new_ffdate = document.getElementById("new_ffdate").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'><td id='ffcode_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_ffcode + "</td><td id='ffname_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_ffname + "</td><td id='fftype_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_fftype + "</td><td id='ffdate_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_ffdate + "</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' id='save_button" + table_len + "' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'></td></tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_ffcode").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_ffname").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_fftype").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_ffdate").value = "";
}
```

```html
<h2>Fee Code Maintenance</h2>
<div id="wrapper">
  <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
    <tr>
      <th>Fee Code</th>
      <th>Fee Name</th>
      <th>Fee Type</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row1">
      <td id="ffcode_row1">AF</td>
      <td id="ffname_row1">Annual Fees</td>
      <td id="fftype_row1">Fixed Fee</td>
      <td id="ffdate_row1">2016-12-21</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('1')">
        <input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
      <td id="ffcode_row2">MF</td>
      <td id="ffname_row2">Medical Fees</td>
      <td id="fftype_row2">Fixed Fee</td>
      <td id="ffdate_row2">2016-12-11</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="edit_button2" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('2')">
        <input type="button" id="save_button2" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('2')">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('2')">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row3">
      <td id="ffcode_row3">TF</td>
      <td id="ffname_row3">Tution Fees</td>
      <td id="fftype_row3">Fixed Fee</td>
      <td id="ffdate_row3">2016-11-11</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="edit_button3" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('3')">
        <input type="button" id="save_button3" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('3')">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('3')">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_ffcode"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_ffname"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="fftype" id="new_fftype">
          <option value="">-select-</option>
          <option value="FF">Fixed Fee</option>
          <option value="RF">Refundable Fee</option>
          <option value="PF">Penalty Fee</option>
          <option value="DF">Discounts</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="date" id="new_ffdate"></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: *"clicking Save the value of checkbox is not stored correctly(it stoes the value not the description)"* When working with controls, the value is the thing that you store, so you need to update the value to have the data you want, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus will do that in that case...will you be able to help with edit section please ?

Comment: Make sure that in the HTML, the `value` attribute(s) have the data that you'd want to extract later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `function edit_row()` does not append the appropriate `select dropdown` to your `table-cell`. Try to change these Lines in `edit_row`:

```
fftype.innerHTML="<select id='fftype_text"+no+"' value='"+fftype_data+"'>
<option value>-select-</option>
<option value='FF'>Fixed Fee</option>
<option value='RF'>Refundable Fee</option>
<option value='PF'>Penalty Fee</option>
<option value='DF'>Discounts</option>
</select>";
```

and for the `save_row()`:

```
var e =document.getElementById("fftype_text"+no);
var fftype_val=e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Here is a [Code Snipet](https://jsfiddle.net/nw05ontn/1/)